# SQL get values from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I got 2 sql table like:

```
user_logs 
-id
-log_date
-log

system_logs
-id
-create_date
-log
```

Is it posible to get values from those tables, and sort them by date?

Comment: Does the data in the tables relate to each other at all?  If not, you can use a UNION to combine the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this query

```
(select id, date, log from user_logs)
union
(select id, date, log from system_logs)
order by date;
```

A better design might be to use one table with columns id, date, log, and log_type where log_type defines whether the log is a user or system log.

Comment: I know it would be better but i havent design this database

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, date FROM user_logs UNION SELECT id, date from system_logs ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Or something like that, at any rate UNION is the keyword you're looking for, [see link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try it by using `UNION`

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT id, date, log FROM user_logs
    UNION
    SELECT id, date, log FROM system_logs
)
ORDER BY date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT *
FROM
( SELECT id,
           date,
           log
    FROM system_logs

    UNION

    SELECT id,
           date,
           log
    FROM user_logs) order by date  DESC
```

OR

```
SELECT id,
               date,
               log
        FROM system_logs

        UNION

        SELECT id,
               date,
               log
        FROM user_logs order by date  DESC
```